# kdenlive 19.04 "crop, scale and tilt effect": controlling the color

Tags: kdenlive

I am using kdenlive 19.04 and it is working like a charm.

Because of a framing error on my part, I need to crop a part of the image. I am doing so using the "Crop, Scale and Tilt" effect (defining the value of "Cropt left" to be a n pixels).

This solves the problem, but the cropped area is simply made black.

Is there a way for me to make this area be a different color (so that it is closer to the background of my video)?